# Making optional parameter of controller action work in Yii

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

I want to make this url, with one mandatory parameter (*id*) and optional parameter (*step*) work in *Yii 1.1*:

```
domain.com/module/index/<id>/<step>
```

This is my controller **ModuleController.php**

```
class ModuleController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex($id, $step)
    {

    }
}
```

I don't have any URL rules set up. Now when I access URLs bellow, both doesn't work and gives me error.

```
...module/index/1
...module/index/1/upload

(Error: Unable to resolve the request "site/error")
```

**Do I need to write an URL rule? How does it look like in my case? Help me to make it work.**

Comment: you need to clarify your problem a bit more, show us an example action you're trying to access and what error you're getting, show the code of `config/main.php`, do you have an `.htaccess` file etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to write url rule. 
It should look like:

```
'module/index/<id:\d+>/<step:\w+>' => 'module/index'
```

And in action same as you did:

```
public function actionIndex($id, $step)
```